# Service shared data with promises

Tags: angularjs

I have two components and I need to show the same data in both components.
My service:

```
export default class Logs {     

    constructor($http, $q, httpService) {
        this.$http = $http;
        this.$q = $q;
        this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
        this.httpService = httpService;
        this.logs = null;
        this.getDefer = this.$q.defer();
        this.loadData();
    }

    loadData() {
        var request = {url: '/logs'};
        this.httpService.getJson(request)
            .then((response) => {
                this.logs = response.data;
                this.getDefer.resolve(this.logs);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                this.getDefer.reject(err);
            });

        return this.getDefer.promise;
    }

    getLogs() {
        return this.getDefer.promise;
    }

    create(newLog) {
        return this.$http.post('http://localhost:9000/api/logs', newLog);
    } 
}

// this is example of using service in component
this.logService.getLogs().then((result) => {                
    this.logs = result;             
});
```

I use promises because, `getLogs` is used in several components and helps me avoid double request on application startup. But now, I am wondering, how can I call `getLogs` to get new data after updating or creating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it a bit wrong. You should return promise from getLogs.

Like:

```
getLogs() {

    if(this.getDefer) return this.getDefer.promise;
    this.getDefer = $q.defer();
    loadData().then(function(data){
        this.getDefer.resolve(data);
        delete this.getDefer;
    });
    return this.getDefer.promise;

}
```

and loadData:

```
loadData() {
    if(this.logs) return $q.when(this.logs); //<-- return cached if exist
    var request = {url: '/logs'};
    return this.httpService.getJson(request)
        .then((response) => {
            this.logs = response.data;
            return response.data;
        });
}
```

So loadData is private method which asyncronously return data, and maybe caches it, and getLogs should be entry point to retrieve this data. So you should use defer in getLogs. If there is already request to loadData - return promise, else - create new defer.

Unfortunately I can't provide Plunker right now, but that's the concept. :)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need